# How I can test $broadcast which is present is $http post method

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Below is code in my service class.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:fileTransferInProgress');
    debugger 
    $http.post("/api/fileTransfer", data, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}                   
    }).success(function(response){
        console.log("I am here");
        $rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:readyState', response);
    }).error(function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('transfer:error');
    });
}, 0);
```

I am trying below code to test the `$broadcast`

```
'use strict';

describe('upload service test ', function () {

    var mockXhr, uploadSvc;
    var $scope, $rootScope, $mockHttp, $httpBackend,$timeout;
    var mockfile = {"name":"File 1", "body":"abcd121212"}; 
    var mockfileType = {"id":"1"}; 
    var mockfileTypeName="test";

    beforeEach(module('questApp'));

    it('should invoke send method of upload service with right paramaeters', function () {

        inject(function($injector) {
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            // $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $mockHttp = $injector.get('$http');            
            uploadSvc=$injector.get('uploadService');
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast');
            $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        })
        $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser : function() {
                return {
                    username : "admin"
                };
            }
        };
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/fileTransfer', {
            'file':mockfile ,
            'fileType':mockfileType,
            'fileTypeName'  :mockfileTypeName   
        }).respond({});
        debugger 
        uploadSvc.send('file','fileType','fileTypeName'); 
        $timeout.flush();
        expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I am not sure what is the wrong but it gives me below error.

> Error: Unexpected request: POST
>   /api/fileTransfer?cacheBuster=1455661017032  Expected POST
>   /api/fileTransfer

Comment: not too hard to figure out you have a cachebuster interceptor that adds a timestamp to url

Comment: what should I do..??

Comment: Maybe you need to flush the $httpBacked

Comment: I added cachebuster in url and it works.. Thanks for your help..